# Generate html table from json url with data from key, value also from parent without key

Tags: javascript, html

Im generating an html table with data from json url.
I want to include parent value without key to these data.

Json structure:

```
{
    "gzpik1gqlnm":
        {"owner_name":"user02","room_name":"131","country":"EN","max":2,"current":1,"password":0},
            "d1vn67n7sgu":
                {"owner_name":"user09","room_name":"254","country":"EN","max":2,"current":1,"password":0}
}
```

Javascript:

```
    setInterval(function(){
  $.getJSON("somejson.url", function(data){
    var room_data = '';
    $("#roomtabletbody").empty();
   
     $.each(data, function(key, value){       
      room_data += '<tr valign="top">';
      room_data += '<td>'+value.country+'</td>';      
      room_data += '<td>'+value.owner_name+'</td>';
      room_data += '<td>'+value.room_name+'</td>';
      room_data += '<td>'+value.current+'/'+value.max+'</td>';
      room_data += '<td>'+value.password+'</td>';
      room_data += '<td><a class="join" href="">Join</a></td>';
      room_data += '<tr>';

    });
    $('#roomtabletbody').append(room_data);
    
  });

        
    }, 1000);
```

generated table:

```
country owner_name  room_name   current/max password
  EN     user02         131          1/2       0
  EN     user09         254          1/2       0
```

table im trying to get at:

```
parent      country owner_name  room_name   current/max password
gzpik1gqlnm    EN    user02         131          1/2       0
d1vn67n7sgu    EN    user09         254          1/2       0
```

Whats the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `room_data += '<td>'+value.country+'</td>';`, add :
`room_data += '<td>'+key+'</td>';`

```
    setInterval(function(){
  $.getJSON("somejson.url", function(data){
    var room_data = '';
    $("#roomtabletbody").empty();
   
     $.each(data, function(key, value){       
      room_data += '<tr valign="top">';
      room_data += '<td>'+key+'</td>';
      room_data += '<td>'+value.country+'</td>';      
      room_data += '<td>'+value.owner_name+'</td>';
      room_data += '<td>'+value.room_name+'</td>';
      room_data += '<td>'+value.current+'/'+value.max+'</td>';
      room_data += '<td>'+value.password+'</td>';
      room_data += '<td><a class="join" href="">Join</a></td>';
      room_data += '<tr>';

    });
    $('#roomtabletbody').append(room_data);
    
  });

        
    }, 1000);
```

Don't forget to add new header in `<thead>`.

Comment: key is parent value.